# Regex XAML issues

Tags: c#, regex, wpf, xaml

was wondering if someone could help me solve this! I'm quite new to Regular Expressions and to be honest, they're a little mind boggling.

I've got a field I want to restrict any whitespace on (to start with), so no blank spaces and press okay. I also want to restrict `"` and `'` within the regex. This is what I have so far:

```
^[\S][^\"\']{0,60}$
```

I've tried lots of different combinations as well as implementing this:

```
^[\S][^\"\'].{0,60}$
```

but I still can't figure it out! the first example nearly works, however it allows someone to input a " and a ' as the first character only, which I don't want them doing at all.

Thanks!

Comment: Where's the connection of the problem to WPF or XAML?

Comment: It's for a personal project, but is it a requirement of website rules to put that here? I'm not here to ask people to solve it, I asked for someone to HELP solve it with me. Just waiting for an explanation now :)

Comment: No, sorry; my question was rather meant to find out whether your *question at hand* requires knowledge of RegEx *and* XAML, or just of RegEx. If it is just about RegEx, you unnecessarily limit your circle of readers because people with RegEx, but without any XAML knowledge might see the tag and the title (a more concrete title helps attract more readers, as well, by the way) and decide against looking into it because they think they need to know both. If you try to reduce your problem description to the least concrete equivalent case you can find, you should theoretically get most answers. ...

Comment: ... With that said, in this case, it is probably irrelevant that you are using XAML and WPF, but knowing that you are using the C# implementation of RegEx is still helpful.

Comment: It was for XAML field mask implementation. :)

Comment: Ok - so, unless the question is specifically about how to input the regex in XAML, the facts that it is about field validation *in WPF and XAML* is irrelevant. The issue would have been exactly the same if it had been for a WinForms text box, or for validating a string read in C# from a file or from console input.

Comment: It does not matter if it is used for XAML field mask implementation.  The question is not about XAML or WPF.

Comment: It says XAML in the title...?

I see what you mean though, but I just thought there may have been a difference between the two, as per the chosen answer; which there is.

If you check the tags too, that may help the with the relevant language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace the first `\S` with the negated character class like `[^\s'"]` which matches any non-space character but not of `'` or double quotes. By this way, you may avoid single quote or double quote as first character.

```
^[^\s'\"][^\"\']{0,60}$
```

In c#

```
@"^[^\s'""][^""']{0,60}$"
```

- `^` start of the line.
- `[^\s'"]` matches any character but not of space or single or double quotes.
- `[^""']{0,60}`matches any character but not of single of double quotes from 0 up-to 60 times. So this would match upto 60 chars.
- `$` End of the line.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper give some time to add explanation.

Comment: Appreciate the answer, appreciate the explanation when it's there too :)

Comment: Since you're new to StackOverflow, I suggest you to read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: All good my friend.

Appreciate your help. At least I know I was on the right track, just a bit of logic missed.